# What type of lock is this?

Tags: lock

Here's a bit of back story I live in Missouri  and their is no laws in place for either a landlord/management or maintenance to give me advanced notice or any notice of any kind to gain entry into my unit but their is also no bill/laws that prohibit me from switching locks out.

Here are pictures below, it's an old hotel converted into studio apartments it was built between 1960 to 1980 not 100% sure when also would it even be possible to do this as well?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually known as a dead bolt type.  A bit more secure than just regular door locks since it is harder to use a credit card to push in.

Answer (score 2):

This is a mortise lockset (meaning the mechanism fits into a pocket carved into the edge of the door) with deadbolt. If you just wanted to rekey it, the cylinder (the portion that recognizes the key) screws in from the face of the door and is kept from unscrewing by a setscrew. That setscrew is accessed by removing the faceplate from the door's edge.

A locksmith can rekey or replace the cylinder, fairly inexpensively, to change which key it responds to. (A few minutes of work if you have the right knowledge, tools, and parts.) Even a large home center is likely to have replacement cylinders, though getting one with the right tailpiece, or moving the tailpiece across, may not be obvious to a beginner.

However: YES, you need to get landlord's permission. Your lease undoubtedly has a clause regarding unauthorized alterations to the rental unit, and even if you don't have a formal lease a court is likely to side with them if they take the cost of regaining access out of your security deposit. If you think their having access now is bad, just wait until you have given them reason to distrust you.

Possible but unwise without permission, and the only way you're going to get permission is if the landlord get a copy of the new key. Which might still be worth talking to them about if you think there are copies of the key in the hands of past tenants it their friends, which is probably a bigger risk.

(ORK Security Services; full-service EXTREMELY part-time locksmith, basically inactive except occasional jobs for friends.)

Comment: This might be obvious, but if you take the cylinder away to a locksmith for a re-key, bring the working key.

Comment: Good point, should have said that. Rekeying can be done without the key, but (a) the key helps confirm this is your lock and (b) doing it without may cost more. If it's a high security cylinder, considerably more.

Answer (score 0):

Having been on committees of Body Corps (thats what they are called here to manage unit trust style arrangements). No surprises that the lock looks like a hotel/apartment style one.

The flush plates are normally either custom made or are a bulk model. And the locks are also bulk models.  It would be difficult to obtain them from standard outlets.  That does not mean that you cant find matching ones.

- The easiest way is to call a locksmith to change the key.
- But its cheaper to remove the cylinder and take it to a locksmith and they can rekey the cylinder/tumbler.  I have done it often on retail models.
- Once you have it apart, you may find a brand name, you can try searching and giving them a call.  but I expect them to not play ball.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find anything like this at your home store. You possibly could find parts at a vintage door and lock shop. Otherwise, you'd need to disassemble it and take the key portion to a home store or locksmith or have one come out and rekey the lock on site.

Read your rental contract carefully before doing this. There is usually wording that forbids doing this. If there's a problem in your unit, leaking pipes, smoke, etc., and the landlord can't get in because you've changed the locks, you'll probably get hit with a hefty locksmith bill or a bill for a new door.